# Why is this javascript file being called?

Tags: javascript

While developing a website, firebug threw me a javascript error linking to the execution of this file (don't just open it yet, it could be malicious, that's the issue here...): http://view.binlayer.com/ad-10476.js

It looks to me that it is malicious, since it seems to be coming from an advertisment company... but impossible to find where the file is called...
Searching the net didn't help me to learn what it is exactly for or where does it comes from.

The file generates this error:

resize_function is not a function
[Break On This Error] resize_function();

And that's how I found about it. I am using some Jquery plugins for this website I'm currently developing, but I don't think it's coming from there, and searching for this url or the filename into my project files didn't return anything...

Is my firefox/ubuntu hacked or do you think it's linked with some dodgy js file...?
I'm not sure if this question should be on stackoverflow since it might not be linked with a development problem but I thought some people might have this issue and not know about it...

Comment: I can't open the linked JavaScript file (oh, wait, that's because I blocked advertisement sites et al.) and we need to look at relevant parts of *your* page source to see where it is included.

Comment: I pointed notepad++ at that file, and all I receive is `// eNR <line break> var blLayer='loaded';`. That's it...

Comment: @josh: this is another weird point. Sometimes when you click on the script url you'll see a lot of code, and yesterday after sometimes I also saw the code you posted. And today it was back to a lot of code. And now you saw it empty. just weird...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be related to other plugins you have installed on firefox, disable all other plugins and see if you still get the error.

Comment: apparently the add-on windows resizer seemed to be the cause... Since I disabled it I don't see the call anymore

Comment: I figured as much, just remember Firefox plugins are javascript too.  Firebug will detect errors from malfunctioning plugins.

Answer (score 1):

[Binlayer](https://binlayer.com/) looks like some pretty agressive german web advertising company. Following some links from a google query using keyword *binlayer* Chrome gave me a few malware warnings. scanning your computer for malware, I'd say.

Searching a bit more, the js [seems benign](http://jsunpack.jeek.org/dec/go?report=40790bc3c070ad2e071c67c0890dce2d9556b9d2) though

Answer (score 0):

You can start by examining all Javascript libraries included in your code. Do you jQuery with plugins? Do you use Doubleclick or another ad-serving network? Any other third-party code?

If you examine each of these, you will likely find that one contains a reference to the binlayer.com script.

Answer (score 0):

Two chances: your project, or your computer is infected. To clear the first, run [grep](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) on your project trying to locate that url. The second is cleared just running ypur project in a different machine. Anyways, there is something dirty that must be washed at soon as possible.